# VisualSearch.js getting facet data

Tags: javascript, json, cakephp, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a VisualSearch.js Query box but builds its facets from the information stored on the database using a REST interface.

For Example an input facet could be "User email" and then as they type the first few letters the users emails are filtered down until the correct one is found.

The issue I am finding is how do I implement this so that it only sends off a request for the user names when it has 'locked in' that facet (or more ideally, when the first letter is press so the search scope is minimized).  Otherwise it seems I would be loading all the facets and their values every time the page is loaded.  This is be huge set of queries being sent off if I also include other searchable objects and values etc.  It would be almost like loading all searchble elements of the whole database so they can then be filtered down.

As a extra pice of info I am using a cakePHP backend for the REST API.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like the `valueMatches` event fits your ticket:

http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#usage

So basically look at `facet == "email" && searchTerm.length == 1` and fire off your AJAX query then, calling the `callback` with the server-filtered data.

Comment: Thank you.  The documentation is actually very clear but I needed a prod to make it all click. Also I found https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/tree/master/docs/* being pasted into http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/* to give you the Docco annotated source code if this helps anyone else.

Comment: or infact just use http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/visualsearch.html and click on the Jump to in the top right to naviagate.